# How to AutoCompleteTextView into Dialog

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have problem with my android program wheere I need put an AutoCompleteTextView into Dialog but not working.

I will share my code:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ExpandableListView myList;
private List<Convenios> convenioList;
private ArrayList<String> convenioNames = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register); }

public void CadastrarNovoConvenio(View view) {
    CadastraConvenio();
}
private void CadastraConvenio()  {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_new_convenio);

    final RadioGroup tipoConvenio = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rbg);
    final Button save = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_cadastrar);
    final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.bt_cancelar);

    final AutoCompleteTextView convenioTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewConvenio);

    dialog.setTitle("Add new Item:");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, convenioNames);
    convenioTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    convenioTextView.setThreshold(1);

    //exibe na tela o dialog
    dialog.show();
  }
```

The problem occurs in this code line:

```
 convenioTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
 convenioTextView.setThreshold(1);
```

Comment: "The problem occurs in this code line:" those lines don't compile? where is an exception at runtime? any other kind of problem in those two lines?

Comment: yes, this lines don't compile, but I don't know whats problem.

Comment: I think that setAdapter not working in my method

Comment: public void CadastrarNovoConvenio(View view) {
    CadastraConvenio();
}
private void CadastraConvenio()  {

Comment: I can put "setAdapter" into View view???

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting for an AutocompliteTextView from activity view.
But it is in dialog view. So you have null in autocompliteTextView variable and get a NullPointerException on convenioTextView.setAdapter(adapter).

You need to change this code:

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView convenioTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewConvenio)
```

To this:

```
    final AutoCompleteTextView convenioTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.getView().findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextViewConvenio);
```